# Args do not unpack

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I'm learning flask and i want to unpack args in inner function. That's my code:

```
def make_bold(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return f"<b>{func(args[0])}</b>"
    return inner


@app.route("/username/<user>")
@make_bold
def username(user):
    return f"Username: {user}"
```

I'm getting an arror "tuple index out of range" even if I add next asterix in

```
return f"<b>{func(*args[0])}</b>"
```

Can I unpack it anywhere else?

Comment: `args[0]` should work as long as the function is being called with a positional argument, and it takes exactly one positional argument.  Are you sure it's being called with a positional argument, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `args` and `kwargs`, you will find that `user` is passed in `kwargs` (by calling `func(user=xxx)`). The problem is that you usually cannot assume how the arguments are passed, so you should write `return f"<b>{func(*args, **kwargs)}</b>"` instead.